# Adding an animation to a random walk plot [Python]

Tags: python, numpy, animation, matplotlib, random

I have written a code that plots random walks. There are `traj` different random walks generated and each consists of `n` steps. I would like to animate their moves. How can I do that?
My code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def random_walk_2D(n, traj = 1):

    for i in range(traj):

        skoki = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, -1]])
        losy = np.random.randint(4, size = n)

        temp = skoki[losy, :]

        x = np.array([[0, 0]])

        temp1 = np.concatenate((x, temp), axis = 0)

        traj = np.cumsum(temp1, axis = 0)

        plt.plot(traj[:, 0], traj[:, 1])
        plt.plot(traj[-1][0], traj[-1][1], 'ro') #the last point

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stands now, you generate traj in one shot. I mean that `traj` in `traj = np.cumsum(temp1, axis = 0)` already contains all the "story" from the beginning to the end. If you want to create an animation that is in "real time", you should not generate `traj` in one shot, but iteratively, plotting new steps as they come. What about doing:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def real_time_random_walk_2D_NT(
    nb_steps, nb_trajs, with_dots=False, save_trajs=False, tpause=.01
    ):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    nb_steps     : integer
                   number of steps
    nb_trajs     : integer
                   number of trajectories
    save_trajs   : boolean (optional)
                   If True, entire trajectories are saved rather than
                   saving only the last steps needed for plotting.
                   False by default.
    with_dots    : boolean (optional)
                   If True, dots representative of random-walking entities
                   are displayed. Has precedence over `save_trajs`. 
                   False by default. 
    tpause       : float (optional)
                   Pausing time between 2 steps. .01 secondes by default.   
    """
    skoki = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, -1]])
    trajs = np.zeros((nb_trajs, 1, 2))
    for i in range(nb_steps):
        _steps = []
        for j in range(nb_trajs):
            traj = trajs[j,:,:]
            losy = np.random.randint(4, size = 1)
            temp = skoki[losy, :]
            traj = np.concatenate((traj, temp), axis = 0)
            traj[-1,:]   += traj[-2,:]
            _steps.append(traj)
        if save_trajs or with_dots:
            trajs = np.array(_steps)
            if with_dots:
                plt.cla()
                plt.plot(trajs[:,i, 0].T, trajs[:,i, 1].T, 'ro') ## There are leeway in avoiding these costly transpositions
                plt.plot(trajs[:,:i+1, 0].T, trajs[:,:i+1, 1].T)
            else:
                plt.plot(trajs[:,-1+i:i+1, 0].T, trajs[:,-1+i:i+1, 1].T)
        else:
            trajs = np.array(_steps)[:,-2:,:]
            plt.plot(trajs[:,:, 0].T, trajs[:,:, 1].T)

        plt.pause(tpause)


real_time_random_walk_2D_NT(50, 6, with_dots=True)
```

[image]

```
real_time_random_walk_2D_NT(50, 6)
```

[image]

Comment: It works, but I really need to generate not only one random walk but several of them. And your code generates a different plot for each step. I would like to have one plot.

Comment: @Hendrra. But you have to generate a different plot for each step, simply because the red point moves. Without this red point, you are right, one could simply accumulate the steps without reploting everything.

Comment: That's a pity. What about adding the red point after generating the random walk?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you. Is it possible to use the same methon to create a 3D random walk?

Comment: @Hendrra. I guess it is. But, please, if my answer does what you want, consider ticking as correct and let's ask another which links to the current one, asking how to turn this (my) answer into its 3d-counterpart. I won't be far :)

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to tick your answer as correct. I will think about it for a while and I'm sure I will need to ask for some details :)